# how to get the bracket pair location?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to know if there is a way in vscode extension developing to get the location of the paired bracket when I know one bracket location?

I am working to developing a definition register on a customed language and the function is inside a paired bracket, I want to highlight the function in peek definition window, so it could simplify the work if I could get the location of the end bracket from the function start bracket

```
(defun listSplit (List start end)
    (let
        (   
            List_in
            List_res
            count
            ind
        )

         List_in = List
         count = 0
         ind = end - start

        (while count < start
            List_in = cdr(List_in)
            count = count + 1
        )

        (while ind > 0
            (if ind > length(List_in) then
                error("index exceed the list")
            else
                List_res = cons(car(List_in) List_res)
                List_in = cdr(List_in)
                ind = ind - 1
            )
        )

        reverse(List_res)
    )
)
```

a method to get the location of end bracket or another method to highlight the function in peek definition window

Comment: I don't think VSCode exposes an API for this. I think the general assumption is that language extensions build some kind of AST that they work with.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I happened to say there is a jump to bracket function in vscode, so I just wondering if there is a api, now I use the stack way to overcome the problem.